# Updating adapter of AutoCompleteTextView from LiveData

Tags: adapter, viewmodel, sql-insert, android-livedata, autocompletetextview

I have a AutoCompleteTextView that I give it 2 different adapters depending on the amount of text that is being present at the textview - if it has 0 characters I want it to display a list of "recently searched" strings adapter, while if it has more than 1 characters I want it to display auto completion list.

My `getRecentlySearchedQueries` method along with the `RecentSearchedViewModel`-

```java
private List<String> recentlySearchedQueries = new ArrayList<>(); // pasted from the top of the class
 @Override
    public void getRecentlySearchedQueries() {
        recentSearchViewModel.getAllQueries().observe(getActivity(), databaseRecentlySearchList -> {
            if (databaseRecentlySearchList == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < databaseRecentlySearchList.size(); i++) {
                Log.d("localDBValue",  "Added value - " + databaseRecentlySearchList.get(i).toString() + "\n");
                String query = databaseRecentlySearchList.get(i).getQuery();
                recentlySearchedQueries.add(query);
            }
            //Log.d("localDBValue", "recent search list value - " + recentlySearchedQueries);
        });
    }

public class RecentSearchViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private RecentSearchRepository recentSearchRepository;
    private LiveData<List<RecentSearchModel>> allRecentlySearched;

    public RecentSearchViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        recentSearchRepository = new RecentSearchRepository(application);
        allRecentlySearched = recentSearchRepository.getAllRecentSearches();
    }

    public void insert(RecentSearchModel model) {
        recentSearchRepository.insert(model);
    }

    public void update(RecentSearchModel model) {
        // add implementation in the future if needed
    }

    public void delete(RecentSearchModel model) {
        // add implementation in the future if needed
    }

    public LiveData<List<RecentSearchModel>> getAllQueries() {
        return allRecentlySearched;
    }
}
```

```java
public class RecentSearchRepository {

    private RecentSearchDao recentSearchDao;
    private LiveData<List<RecentSearchModel>> allRecentSearches;

    public RecentSearchRepository(Application application) {
        MarketplaceDatabase database = MarketplaceDatabase.getRecentSearchInstance(application);
        recentSearchDao = database.recentSearchDao();
        allRecentSearches = recentSearchDao.getRecentSearchList();
    }

    public void insert(RecentSearchModel model) {
        new RecentSearchRepository.InsertRecentSearchAsyncTask(recentSearchDao).execute(model);
    }

    public void update (RecentSearchModel model) {
        //TODO - implement in future if needed
    }

    public void delete(RecentSearchModel model) {
        //TODO - implement in future if needed
    }

    public LiveData<List<RecentSearchModel>> getAllRecentSearches() {
        return allRecentSearches;
    }

    private static class InsertRecentSearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<RecentSearchModel, Void, Void> {

        private RecentSearchDao recentSearchDao;

        public InsertRecentSearchAsyncTask(RecentSearchDao recentSearchDao) {
            this.recentSearchDao = recentSearchDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(RecentSearchModel... recentSearchModels) {
            recentSearchDao.insert(recentSearchModels[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class UpdateRecentSearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<RecentSearchModel, Void, Void> {

        private RecentSearchDao recentSearchDao;

        public UpdateRecentSearchAsyncTask(RecentSearchDao recentSearchDao) {
            this.recentSearchDao = recentSearchDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(RecentSearchModel... recentSearchModels) {
            recentSearchDao.update(recentSearchModels[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@Dao
public interface RecentSearchDao {

    @Insert()
    void insert(RecentSearchModel model);

    @Update
    void update(RecentSearchModel model);

    @Delete
    void delete(RecentSearchModel model);

    @Query("select * from recent_search_table")
    LiveData<List<RecentSearchModel>> getRecentSearchList();

}
```

```java
@Entity(tableName = "recent_search_table")
public class RecentSearchModel {


    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int ID;

    private String query;

    public RecentSearchModel(){

    }

    public RecentSearchModel(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RecentSearchModel{" +
                "query='" + query + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof RecentSearchModel)
            return this.query.equalsIgnoreCase(((RecentSearchModel) obj).query);
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, what I am doing here is for start getting all values inside my local DB and adding them to my String list that is part of the adapter. So far so good.

The issue I am facing is that the adapter won't show the amount of strings available in the list that populates it. In fact, it sometimes shows a view half-cut with wierd information, sometimes does not show anything and sometimes shows part of the corrent information. What am I missing?

Another thing I am facing is that the "recently searched" adapter won't work when clicking on the AutoCompleteTextView - it only works when typing and deleting values so the char length is 0. How can I make it work from start of focus?

Here is the way I am populating the information to the ViewModel -

```java
 /**
     * Shows the searched products following
     */
    @Override
    public void getSearchedProducts(String searchedQuery) {
        MarketplaceUtils.getSearchedProducts(searchedQuery, marketApiCalls, false, initialSearchTake, initialMarketplacePage, new MarketplaceUtils.OnProductsFetchCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<MiniProductModel> list) {
                if (!searchedQuery.equals(currentSearchedText))
                    return;
                if (list == null) {
                    //reaching here means we do not have a result to show to the UI so we empty the list.
                    currentProductList.clear();
                    productsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return;
                }

                if (searchedQuery.length() > 3 && searchAutoCompleteStrings.contains(searchedQuery)) {
                    Log.d("localDBValue", "searchedValue - " + searchedQuery);
                    recentSearchViewModel.insert(new RecentSearchModel(searchedQuery));
                }


                mPresenter.setDiscoverProductsLayoutVisibility(View.GONE);
                currentProductList.clear();
                currentProductList.addAll(list);
                productsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                Log.d("searchedProducts", throwable.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

The default behaviour for `@Insert` method of Room is `OnConflictStrategy.ABORT` - so what I did is to implement `equals()` method to verify that the RecentSearchModels that are being compared are compared by their string value. Still does seems to effect anything.

Comment: Try this autoCompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus) {
                    autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
                }
            }
        });

Comment: and add this as well autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.length() == 0) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter("");
                }
                autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
      }
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {            }
        });

Comment: these changes will solve search issue when input is zero

Comment: Thank you. one problem solved. Now I need to address the second one, if you could help that would be awesome.

Comment: Actually I didn't understand your second question I do understand that you have 2 adapter tied to one autocompletetextview one when there is no user input and other when user starts typing correct?

Comment: correct. The issue is that the one adapter that is being displayed when there is no input does not save the information as needed, that's my issue. I want it to update the array that fills that adapter when search is complete, but it does not update the array at time and I get some duplicated results also.